# Webhooks (Push Notifications) for YouTube comments as Push notification

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm searching for web-hooks that give me comments and replies for each and every video that I post on YouTube to my endpoint as JSON Payload just like Facebook, Instagram, Twitter and Google My Business has. I got [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) but this is of no use, as there is no option where I can get comments for the Video. Can anyone please suggest any blogs or a way to which I can solve my problem? Any help would be appreciated.